# Count rows and exclude row in next count

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to count the number of rows within a group that meet a condition, but exclude those row counts if they appear in the consequent count for another level. ***Essentially, I am trying to count new and unique occurences of individuals within consequent censuses so I can create a cumulative distribution by census.***

Please note that the sample dataset is from a sample from a larger dataset that has unequal `n()` values by treatment. Additionally, individuals may appear in census but not the next.

#### Sample Dataset

```
sampledata <- data.frame(treatment = c("A", "A", "H", "H", "H", "A", "A", "H", "H", "H",
                                       "A", "A", "H", "H", "H", "A", "A", "H", "H", "H"), 
                         individual = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
                                        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                         census = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
                                    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"),
                         value = c("0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4", "3", "0",
                                   "0", "0", "8", "5", "2", "0", "1", "15", "7", "4"))
```

#### This is my code which I tried using

- `total` is the total number of individuals of `treatment` and `census`.
- `count` is the number of individuals with a `value>0` for that `treatment` and `census`.
- `cum.sum` is the cumulative individuals with `value>0` for that `treatment` and beginning from census 1

If I was able to only get unique individuals (not counted in a previous census), then the `cum.sum` should never be greater than `n`.

Unfortunately as you can see, the output produces a cumulative number that is greater than the actual sample size `n`.

```
library(dplyr)
sampledata$value <- as.numeric(sampledata$value)
sampledata2 <- sampledata %>%
  group_by(treatment, census) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(value>0), total=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  mutate(cum.sum=cumsum(count))
```

#### Expected Output

```
          treatment census count total cum.sum
1         A         1      0     2       0
2         A         2      0     2       0
3         A         3      0     2       0
4         A         4      1     2       1
5         H         1      1     3       1
6         H         2      1     3       2
7         H         3      1     3       3
8         H         4      0     3       3
```

#### EDIT/EXPLANATION FOR EXPECTED OUTPUT

For `treatment=H`, `census=4`, the variable `count=0`. The reason why it is 4 is because the 3 individuals that a value above 0 throughout the census had already been detected. I think naming the `count` variable as it is, may have confused readers.

The `count` variable is supposed to DETECT rows in the `census` (by `treatment`) that have a `value>0` and **HAVE NOT BEEN DETECTED BEFORE.**

Comment: I don't quite understand your expected output. Why do you say that the number of individuals with value > 0 for treatment = H and group = 4 is 0? It should be 3, right?

Comment: I have added an explanation at the end of my original post. The count variable is supposed to DETECT rows in the census (by treatment) that have a value>0 and have NOT been detected before. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can just calculate an additional variable to adjust how `count` is defined.

Adding `never_detected_before` to your code:

```
library(dplyr)

sampledata2 <- sampledata %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value))) %>% 

  group_by(treatment, individual) %>% 
  arrange(treatment, individual, census) %>% 
  mutate(never_detected_before = cumsum(value>0) <= 1) %>% 

  group_by(treatment, census) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(value>0 & never_detected_before), total=n()) %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  mutate(cum.sum=cumsum(count))
```

Also note that `group_by()` by default overrides existing groups so that `ungroup()` is not needed.